# How to use matplotlib with many data points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, axis

In my problem I have about 7500 data points (Games) that each have a separate value assigned to it (Loss). My first list consists of integers of 0-200 and my other list consists of zeros only.

When I now plot them the x-axis shows a point for each separate value from 0-200. Instead, I only want steps show that are a multiple of 50, so 0,50,100,150,200. How do I do this in matplotlib?

[image: sample plot]

My code is pretty basic and as follows:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(games[:200],loss[:200])
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you want to plot numbers, don't try to plot strings.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to typecast before plotting. That was my problem. I appreciate your answer.